# Correlation for a discrete time markov chain

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

## Question

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an irreducible Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC) with finite state space $S$, transition matrix $P$ and steady state $\pi$. Assume that we are ''far enough'' in time that we may assume that for all $n$ $X_n \overset{d}{=} \pi$ then we define:
$$
\ell_m := \mbox{Corr}(X_{n}, X_{n+m}),
$$
since we are working with a Markov chain one would think that for all $m$, $\ell_m$ can be expressed in function of $\ell_1$. My question is : Is there a good way to see this and what this relation is? i.e. find for each $m$ the function $f_m$ s.t. $\ell_m = f_m(\ell_1)$. As show below, for the special case $|S| = 2$ the function $f_m$ is just given by $f_m(x) := x^m$.

## Special Case

In a very special case : a state space with only 2 states we have with $\pi = [\alpha\quad 1-\alpha]$ that for some constant $a \in \left[\max\left(2-\frac{1}{\alpha},0\right),1\right]$:
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 1-a\\
\frac{\alpha-\alpha a}{1-\alpha} & \frac{\alpha a - 2\alpha + 1}{1-\alpha}.
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This allows one to see (by trivial calculations) that $\ell_1 = \mbox{Det}(P)$. But then we see, as $\ell_m$ is just $\ell_1$ for the adapted process $Y_n := X_{n\cdot m}$:
$$
\ell_m = \mbox{Det}(P^m) = \mbox{Det}(P)^m = \ell_1^m
$$

Comment: I know how correlation of real-valued random variables is defined, but how do you define the correlation of random variables taking values in an abstract set $S$?

Comment: You may assume $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I guess I'm also a little confused by the question.  It certainly can't be true that there is a single family of functions $f_m$ that does the job for every possible Markov chain, or even for every possible Markov chain on a given fixed state space $S$.  And if you allow the family $f_m$ to depend on the chain, then it is trivially true since you just set $f_m(\ell_1)$ to be whatever $\ell_m$ is for that chain.

Comment: Yes you make a very valid point.

Comment: I will reconsider my question.

Comment: Okay I reconsidered it but yes this "one family of functions $f_m$" is the thing I was hoping for that it would exist. The two dimensional case seemed to hint its existence in my eyes but I don't have any justification for this.

Comment: I think if you play around with $|S|=3$ for a while you'll be able to find two chains with the same value for $\ell_1$ but different values for $\ell_2$.

Comment: Okay great advice. I'll try to do that tomorrow. I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple counterexample that is a bit too long for a comment.

Consider two discrete-time Markov chains on $S=\{1,2,3\}$ with the following two transition matrices:
$$
P_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \;,
\quad 
P_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Both chains are irreducible and leave the uniform distribution invariant. The corresponding discrete-time Markov chains have the same lag-$1$ equilibrium autocorrelation, i.e.,  $\ell_1=-1/2$.  However, for $k>1$ their lag-$k$ autocorrelations  are quite different since the first chain is periodic with period $3$ while the second chain's lag-$k$ autocorrelation decays to zero with $k$.

This is not quite a counterexample, since the first chain does not have a steady-state or limiting  distribution.  To correct this deficiency, we break its periodicity by slightly perturbing its entries using a small parameter $\epsilon>0$:
$$
\tilde P_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1-\epsilon & \epsilon \\
\epsilon & 0 & 1-\epsilon \\
1-\epsilon & \epsilon & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$ The lag-$k$ correlation functions for the chains with transition matrices $\tilde P_1$ (blue line) and $P_2$ (black line) are plotted below with $\epsilon=1/25$ (chosen for visualization purposes only).  The inset shows the first few lag correlations.  Note that $\ell_1$ is the same for the two chains.

[image]

**ADD**

As the OP (HolyMonk) points out in the comments to this answer: for $\tilde P_1$ (given above) and for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $\ell_1 = -1/2$ and $\ell_2 = -1/2−3(−1+ϵ)ϵ$.

Comment: Indeed, very nice example.

Comment: I have done the calculations and in fact we just have $\ell_1 = \frac{-1}{2}$ regardless of the value of $\varepsilon$ whilst for example $\ell_2 = -3 \varepsilon^2 + 3 \cdot \varepsilon - \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @HolyMonk That is not quite what I get.  For $\tilde P_1$ I get $\pi \propto (1-\epsilon, (1-\epsilon)^{-1}-\epsilon,1) $ and $\ell_1 =  (3-4 \epsilon + 3 \epsilon^3 -2\epsilon^4) (-6 + \epsilon (11+(-7+\epsilon) \epsilon))^{-1}$.  So for $\epsilon=1/25$ we have $\ell_1 \approx -0.5098$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\pi$? I usually use this notation for the stationary distribution/steady state but I would think this is just $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}]$ here?

Comment: @HolyMonk That's right: I am using your notation for the steady state distribution.   The steady distribution for $\tilde P_1$ is no longer uniform when $\epsilon>0$ since $[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}] \tilde P_1 = [ \frac{1-\epsilon}{3}, \frac{1+\epsilon}{3}, \frac{1}{3} ]$.

Comment: I could be really dumb here but:
$[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}] \begin{pmatrix}

Comment: I could be really dumb here but:
$[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}] \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1- \varepsilon & \varepsilon\\
\varepsilon & 0 & 1- \varepsilon\\
1 - \varepsilon & \varepsilon & 0
\end{pmatrix} = [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}]$? Which makes the steady distribution $[1/3,1/3,1/3]$.

Comment: You are right.  Sorry about that.  I misplaced one of the $\epsilon$'s in the second row of the transition matrix I was considering.  With the correction, I get $\ell_1 = -1/2$ and $\ell_2 = -\frac{1}{2} - 3 (-1+\epsilon) \epsilon$, which agrees with the result you gave in your earlier comment.

Comment: Yes, doesn't make your example less good :)!

Comment: What routine did you use to compute $\ell_n$?
I do have a routine to calculate $\ell_n$ but it's rather slow, it takes a few minutes to calculate the first 20 $\ell_n$, so I do not even attempt to go up to $100$.